# Changing columns into rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I have the following script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [L_ID] 
      ,[tTerminal].[C_Name]
      ,[C_Place]
      ,CAST(CAST([B_SubBranch]AS BINARY) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SubBranch1 
      ,ISNULL(( SELECT c_name FROM [cOffice] WHERE c_code = CAST(CAST([B_SubBranch]AS BINARY) AS VARCHAR(20))),'') AS SBname1 

      ,CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING([B_SubBranch],31, 31)AS BINARY) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SubBranch2
      ,ISNULL(( SELECT c_name FROM [cOffice] WHERE c_code = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING([B_SubBranch],31, 31)AS BINARY) AS VARCHAR(20))),'') AS SBname2 

  FROM [tTerminal], [cOffice] ORDER BY [L_ID]
```

Which gives the following results

```
L_ID    C_Name              C_Place                SubBranch1  SBname1                             SubBranch2   SBname2
4200    000042 VTerminal    Sr Windhoek 000042     20048       Meat Market Windhoek 020048         45395        Hungry Lion Windhoek  045395        
4201    000042 Virdi 4000   Sr Windhoek 000042     20048       Meat Market Windhoek 020048         45395        Hungry Lion Windhoek 045395     
8400    000084 VTerminal    Sr Swakopmund 000084   20080       Meat Market Swakopmund 020080       31314        Hungry Lion Swakopmund 031314       
8401    000084 Virdi 4000   Sr Swakopmund 000084   20080       Meat Market Swakopmund 020080       31314    Hungry Lion Swakopmund 031314       
11500   000115 VTerminal    Sr Vryburg 000115      20111       Meat Market Vryburg 020111               
11501   000115 Virdi 4000   Sr Vryburg 000115      20111       Meat Market Vryburg 020111
```

What I would like the script to do is this:

```
 L_ID   C_Name              C_Place                SubBranch  SBname                               
 4200   000042 VTerminal    Sr Windhoek 000042     20048       Meat Market Windhoek 020048         
 4200   000042 VTerminal    Sr Windhoek 000042     45395       Hungry Lion Windhoek  045395 
 4201   000042 Virdi 4000   Sr Windhoek 000042     20048       Meat Market Windhoek 020048          
 4201   000042 Virdi 4000   Sr Windhoek 000042     45395       Hungry Lion Windhoek 045395
```

Basically, instead of making a new column each time for the 'Sub Branches', make a row underneath for each one.
I tried renaming them all to the same Column Name, but then it just creates duplicate column names. Please help!

Comment: Are you storing all the different sub branches as a single string, e.g. for 4200 do you have `"20048               45395"` as the value for `B_Branch`? If so your problem is not with your query, but with your database. You need to normalise it. Why as are you casting to binary, then to VARCHAR in the predicates? Is the cross join between `cOffice` and `tTerminal` intentional? Could you supply some sample data from each table?

Answer (score 0):

Few thing you could try:

- Remove the DISTINCT and the CAST
- Extend the ORDER BY to: L_ID, C_Name, C_Place, SubBranch

Otherwise you'd have to dive into the more complex world of GROUP BY, subqueries and pivotting..